# Drupal 7 db_select ORDER BY

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7, sql-order-by

I am trying to work out how to convert the order by code bellow that I am currently using in db_query to db_select. 
The query sorts users by how well the match the current logged in user. I am also using some WHERE statements to remove users that are totally incompatible before running the rest through the order by calculation to speed up the query, so I don't want to run it as a select expression.

```
ORDER BY (10*(s.field_smoker_value * :field_smoker_pref_value) +
  10*(sp.field_smoker_pref_value * :field_smoker_value) +
  15*(p.field_pet_value * :field_pet_pref_value) +
  15*(pp.field_pet_pref_value * :field_pet_value) +
  5*(c.field_couple_value * :field_couple_pref_value) +
  5*(cp.field_couple_pref_value * :field_couple_value))ASC
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231524/drupal-db-select-pdo-statement-order-by-case could help you sort out your problem.

Comment: Thanks this will work but I am trying to avoid using the select expression as suggested in the link above as this will mean running the calculation on lots of rows that I will then remove by a WHERE operator. The order by equation will eventually be 5 times as long as it is currently and there will be a lot of rows so any speed gain will really matter.